# JBoss 7/EAP6.1 deploy exploded ear in a cluster

Tags: jboss7.x, cluster-computing

I have an **exploded ear** (ejb3 and war). 
First, I successfully deployed it on 1 jboss EAP 6.1 in standalone mode.

Now, I try to create a cluster from 2 JBoss EAP 6.1, each in **standalone** mode.
I'm using the following command with the standalone-ha.xml file out of the box:

```
bin\standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml
```

and

```
bin\standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
```

In front of the jboss cluster, I have a httpd apache + mod_cluster.
( I'm following this [guideline](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/21/clustering-in-jboss-as7eap-6/))

What is working as expected:

- load balancing with mod_cluster : ok
- sticky session : ok
- My exploded ear is deployed on each standalone jboss

What is **NOT** working as expected:

- Session replication
- The 2 JBoss do not seem to start the "cluster service".

In fact, there is no error in the logs.

If I try with a **packaged** demo war file (found with a tutorial), the Session replication is working. 
In the logs file, the following lines:

> 17:34:21,034 INFO  MSC service thread 1-4(:)
>   [org.jboss.as.clustering] - JBAS010238: Number of cluster members: 1

only appears with the packaged war file.
If I deploy my own exploded ear, *or if I deploy an exploded version of demo war*, the line above does not show up.

Yes, my ear contains a war directory that contains web.xml file. This one contains a

```
<distributable/>
```

tag.

Is anyone know if there is some limitation with clustering and exploded ear/war ?

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my ear was not "distributable" due to https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/ 1.44 and especially because of the issue 321 (https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/issues/detail?id=321).

Hope it can helps.